# Kotlin coroutine in lifecycleScope doesn't block main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, coroutine

I am confused about coroutines in ViewModels.

My question is pretty simple: **why does it seem like the following coroutine doesn't block UIThread?** (UI is still smooth while coroutine is running)

My fragment right here:

```
class FragmentSeePaths : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_see_paths),
        PathRecyclerAdapter.OnSetPathForWidgetListener {
    private val pathViewModel: PathViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSeePathsBinding
    private lateinit var listener: OnAddLineRequestListener

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
    }

    private fun observeWidgetPath() {
        pathViewModel.getUserWidgetPath().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it != null) {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    val times = pathViewModel.fetchBusTime(it)
                    updateUI(it, times)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

And here are the shotened ViewModel with the fetchBusTime method:

```
suspend fun fetchBusTime(path: Path): Pair<List<Time>?, List<Time>?> {
        Log.v("fetchBusTimeUI", Thread.currentThread().name) // Main

        // Some network requests made with Retrofit
        val timesResponseStartPoint: GinkoTimesResponse? = repository.getTimes(
                path.startingPoint.startName,
                path.line.lineId,
                path.isStartPointNaturalWay
        )

        val timesResponseEndPoint: GinkoTimesResponse? = repository.getTimes(
                path.endingPoint.endName,
                path.line.lineId,
                path.isStartPointNaturalWay
        )

        return timesResponseStartPoint to timesResponseEndPoint
}
```

Comment: Did you read any documentation about what coroutines are? Suspend functions never block the main thread (as long as they are written correctly). They suspend execution of the coroutine (which in the case of the main thread frees it up to do whatever else it needs to for the UI) until they return.

Comment: Yeah i read about it. The thing is, whats the point of putting the coroutines in the dipatcher.IO or Dispatcher.default ?
I think the video make me realize what is happening in my code. In launching the coroutine in the main thread, and when Retrofit gets called, Retrofit automatically switch context. Make sense ?

Comment: Any suspend function that is written correctly will switch away from the Main dispatcher whenever running blocking code. The common idiom for a simple suspend function is `suspend fun x(param: Int) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { /* some blocking code */ }`. A suspend function that doesn’t call any blocking code, just other suspend functions and non-blocking functions, won’t need to explicitly change dispatchers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`launch` allows us to start a coroutine in the background and keep working in the meantime. `Suspending` functions may suspend the execution of the current coroutine without blocking the current thread. We can start a coroutine under any of the below dispatchers.

1. dipatcher.IO -> Network operation
2. dispatcher.Main -> On main thread
3. dispatcher.Default -> for CPU intensive operation

To explain you in detail, I am taking an example from the documentation :-

```
fun main() { 
    GlobalScope.launch { // launch new coroutine in background and continue
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello,") // main thread continues here immediately
    runBlocking {     // but this expression blocks the main thread
        delay(2000L)  // ... while we delay for 2 seconds to keep JVM alive
    } 
}
```

The comments should speak for themselves. This will print “Hello,” immediately, and add “World!” after a second.
This is the same thing that will work with your code, the suspend function `fetchBusTime()` will be executed without blocking the thread and after the operation completed inside this method, it will execute `updateUI(it, times)`.

For more details on this please go through this article [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/kotlin-coroutines-from-basics-to-advanced-ad3eb1421006)